# YUI scrollView arrows not working after page scroll

Tags: pagination, scrollview, yui, arrows

I made use of YUI scrollview to make a menu construction with touch, flick and arrows. However, for some reason the arrows have a bug.

When the page is loaded the first time it works fine, however, as soon as the user scrolls the page with its mouse of with swipe (on tablet or phone) the arrows do not work any more. When I swipe the content, the arrows magically come to live and work again.

This is the script I use for scrollView:

```
YUI().use('scrollview-base', 'scrollview-paginator', function(Y) {

    var scrollView = new Y.ScrollView({
        id: "scrollview",
        srcNode : '#clientslider-content',
        width : 950,
        flick: {
            minDistance: 10,
            minVelocity: 0.3,
            axis: "x"
        }
    });

    scrollView.plug(Y.Plugin.ScrollViewPaginator, {
        selector: 'li'
    });

    scrollView.render();


    var content = scrollView.get("contentBox"); 
    var scrollViewCurrentX = $('#clientslider-content').offset();

    content.delegate("click", function(e) {

        var scrollViewNewX = $('#clientslider-content').offset();
        var scrollMarginL = (scrollViewNewX.left-2);
        var scrollMarginR = (scrollViewNewX.left+2);

        if (scrollViewCurrentX.left < scrollMarginL || scrollViewCurrentX.left > scrollMarginR)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        }               
    }, ".clientlink");

    content.delegate("mousedown", function(e) {
        scrollViewCurrentX = $('#clientslider-content').offset();               
        e.preventDefault();            
    }, "a, img");

    Y.one('#clientslider-next').on('click', Y.bind(scrollView.pages.next, scrollView.pages));
    Y.one('#clientslider-prev').on('click', Y.bind(scrollView.pages.prev, scrollView.pages));

});
```

You can find a demo here:
http://www.circlesoftware.nl/demo/test.html

To reproduce:
 - load the page
 - press the right button (do not do anything else)
 - scroll down with your mouse
 - arrows are broken now
To fix:
 - just grap the content of the slider, swipe it
 - try the left or right button and they work again

Does anyone have ANY idea what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Problem came from the library itself it seems, was using 3.7.3, upgrade it to 3.9.1 and seems to be solved now:
http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.9.1/build/yui/yui-min.js